# Mesh auto unhide when select another object

Tags: mesh, edit-mode

Please tell me how to "permanently" hide part of a mesh.
In edit mode, I  select mesh of object "A" then hide, but when I select another object, that part of object "A" is automatically unhidden.
Any help would be really appreciated

Comment: Welcome to the site :) We like to stick to one question per post, in order to keep things organized and focused. Consider splitting this into two separate posts

Answer (score 1):

One way is with the [*Mask* modifier](http://blender.org/manual/modeling/modifiers/generate/mask.html):

[image]

1. In edit mode, select the part of the object you want to hide (or the inverse; the part you want to remain visible)
2. Create and assign a *vertex group* in *Properties > Object Data*
3. Add a mask modifier and specify the vertex group. Click the invert button if needed.

Comment: Thank you very much , i really appricate your efforts , i will try it :)